# React.js Update component passed as argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing web xmpp chat using React.js and Strophe.js, and I run in quite problem.

XMPP connection is stored single object, but what is tricky, connection status change is handled by class, where i can store the true handler (because displaying connection status will have 2 different views, and Strophe.OnConnection handler cannot be changed after initialization)

What I want to achieve is to pass component to a function, to render itself with new props, something like it

```
var statusHandler = {
    handler:"",
    setStatus: function(status) {
        React.render(<this.handler value=status/>, dom);
    }
}

var firstContainer = React.render(<anotherComponent/>, dom);
statusHandler.handler = firstContainer;
XMPPConnection(login,pwd,statusHandler.setStatus);

//now changing component
var secondContainer = React.render(<anotherComponent/>, dom);
statusHandler.handler = secondContainer;
```

Or its possible to define callback on component,and pass it as argument (but not a static function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea that may clean up your code would be to emit an event when the connection status changes. Then inside your react components inside `componentDidMount` listen to that event and set your state accordingly.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/11114/

Comment: It looks promising, I will test it :)